# A sequence of random variables, such that CDF converges

Tags: probability-theory

> Given a sequence of random variables $X_n$, is it true that for some
>   of its subsequences $X_{n(k)}$ there is a random variable $X$ such
>   that $F_{X_{n(k)}}(t) → F_{X}(t)$ for all $t ∈ \mathbb{R}$. (F is a CDF.)

I guess it's true, but have I trouble proving that, and don't even understand how to approach that. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true as stated.  For instance, if $P(X_n=n)=1$ for all $n$, your supposed $X$ would have cdf. $F_X(t)=0$ for all $t$.

But it is close to something true & important: [Prokhorov's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokhorov%27s_theorem), which covers the case where the $X_n$ are ``tight'', that is, for every $\epsilon$ there is a $K$ such that $P|X_n|>K)<\epsilon$ for all $n$.  (Which of course is not satisfied by the example in the above paragraph.)